# Two way lookup within a sortable/filterable Excel table

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, lookup

I am looking to return the intersection of a given row and column in an Excel table, where the sort/filter of the table will be changed.

I have found lots of resources on how to do a two way lookup in a static Excel 2D array/table that will never change order, but I am running into trouble trying to reference these intersections of a given row and column in a table that will be filtered and sorted by users. Filters and sorts are changing the cells' locations, breaking my references.

Ideally, the solution should look something like this:

```
=INDEX(TABLE,MATCH("PRODUCT",A:A,0),MATCH("COMPANY",$1:$1,0))
```

or, something like this,

```
=TABLE[[#Data],[PRODUCT] TABLE[[#All],[COMPANY]]
```

My environment is a table where the left most column is a list of products, and the top most row are column headers listing company names. The cell values at the intersection are quantities of products per company.

Thank you for any help, in advance!!

---

EDIT: Here's a visual example,

```
PRODUCTS    COMPANY A   COMPANY B
PRODUCT #1  1           2
PRODUCT #2  3           1
```

Referencing "COMPANY B", "PRODUCT #1" would return 2-- what's key is that the reference isn't broken by the table being filtered or sorted.

Comment: Data, even if fictitious, would be very helpful in understanding the problem and desired solution.

Comment: Thanks @Isolated, added a visual to OP.

Comment: But do you also have data behind the scenes? That is also needed if you want help on this one. Data, then desired output, then what you've tried is the best way to pose your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first formula works, if made to select adjacent cell.

```
=INDEX(TABLE,MATCH("PRODUCT",A:A,0)-1,MATCH("COMPANY",$1:$1,0))
```

Revisiting later, it was selecting cell underneath the intended. Weird. Not positive why, but seems no one really took a look here. Folks at /r/Excel understood, though without any ideas as to why it picks cell below intended.